# Will mapping a custom domain remove the appspot.com domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

As the title states; will google appengine remove the x.appspot.com domain if a custom one is mapped? Or will the unique x.appspot.com always work, regardless of custom domain mapping? Both in a short and long-term perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x.appspot.com will always work.

The appspot domain is really important because it allows you to directly access different versions and modules.  For example, if you have only a default module and multiple versions of it, you can access the versions like this:

- v1.x.appspot.com
- v2.x.appspot.com

The default version will be at x.appspot.com.